# Vexillology - Greece Flag waving Effect without canvas

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am developing Greece Country Flag

- I am not supposed to use Canvas :(
- I am not supposed to use any images :(

I have done good progress in developing into final shape, but i am unable to code close to waving effect, i tried applying border radius etc, but they did not give me any good result.

Please have a look at [Code Pen Demo](http://cdpn.io/kcEmA)

Please check [code with comments at Code pen](http://codepen.io/Sud_/pen/kcEmA)

Could some one please suggest me any css tricks to get waving effect with pure css, any help is highly appreciated :).

Comment: Whats wrong with the flag at codepen?

Comment: @user2067005: I want wave effects for the flag!